# How to organize columns and rows of a matrix mathematically

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, permutations, matrix-calculus, permutation-matrices

I have a matrix M whose size i.e $8$x$8$ , as follows:

[image]

where $x$ can be any non-zero value. . I need to organize this matrix $M$ to move the elements $M$(3:4,3:4) to be in positions $N$(7:8,7:8). On the other hand, the elements of $M$(5:8,5:8) to be moved into $N$(3:6,3:6). It means that the matrix $N$ should be as follows:

[image]

My question, how should it be the permutation matrix to be multiplied by $M$ in order to get $N$? Or if there is another mathematical expression we can use to get matrix $N$ based on M. I need it in general case, it means whatever the size of matrix $M$, we can organize it to get the other matrix as in matrix $N$.

EDIT:

What I need exactly is to move the elements in red into last rows and column and then move the elements in blue into their places as follows:

[image]

and the resultant matrix is as below:

[image]

Comment: What does "M(3:4,3:4) to be in positions N(7:8,7:8)." mean? M(3,3), M(3,4),.. to where?

Comment: @C.F.G for example $M(3:4,3:4)$,   The first  part before the comma 3:4 describe the columns number of the matrix and the second part after the column denotes the rows.  for example from column 3 to 4 and from rows 3 to 4 from the matrix $M$. that should be moved to another positions in $N(7:8, 7:8)$.

Comment: If it is not important that how to derive final matrix from first one, I can do this instead: interchange columns  $3\leftrightarrow 7$ and  $4\leftrightarrow 8$ then rows  $3\leftrightarrow 7$ and  $4\leftrightarrow 8$. Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you want to find the matrix that swap  two rows or columns just swap that rows or columns in the Identity matrix. For example if you want to swap columns $3\leftrightarrow 7$ then you should multiply (from left side or right?) your matrix to the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\color{red}{0}&0&0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0\\ 
0&1&\color{red}{0}&0&0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{1}&0&0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{0}&1&0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{0}&0&1&0&\color{blue}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{0}&0&0&1&\color{blue}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{0}&0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
0&0&\color{red}{0}&0&0&0&\color{blue}{0}&1\\\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}1&0&\color{blue}{0}&0&0&0&\color{red}{0}&0\\ 
0&1&\color{blue}{0}&0&0&0&\color{red }{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0&0&0&\color{red}{1}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{0}&1&0&0&\color{red}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0&1&0&\color{red}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0&0&1&\color{red}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0&\color{red}{0}&0\\
0&0&\color{blue}{0}&0&0&0&\color{red}{0}&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

**Example:** Verify the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\ 
4&5&6\\
7&8&9 \end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}1&\color{red}{0}&\color{blue}{0}\\ 
0&\color{red}{0}&\color{blue}{1}\\
0&\color{red}{1}&\color{blue}{0} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\\ 
4&6&5\\
7&9&8 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I got what you mean, but what's about if I want to swap each element in the matrix, for example, in your last example, I want to swap the element 5 to be in the place of 9, and vice versa.

Comment: I added an example of what I mean exactly, it's to move sub-matrix in red and then swap it with that bigger sub-matrix in blue.